# Enzyme, how to find a child of wrapper by attribute?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, cheerio, enzyme

I have the following React component in a Redux application.

```
<Modal>
<Modal.Header closeButton onClick={props.onHide}>
    <Modal.Title>A Sample Modal</Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>
</Modal.Body>
```

Now, in my test code, I have the following

```
const wrapper = mount(<modal/>);
const closeButton = wrapper.find("['closeButton']");
expect(closeButton.length).to.equal(1); // error - expected 0 to be 1
```

But the selector does not find the close button. Help?

**update:** I am using the React Modal library, and the contents of the HTML seem to change.

Answer (score 6):

Just giving a prop without value to a component is equivalent to `prop={true}`. Thus you should be able to use an [Enzyme object property selector](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#4-object-property-selector) to find the element like this:

```js
const closeButton = wrapper.find({ closeButton: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `['closeButton']` is not a valid selector. It should be `[closeButton]` without the `'`

e.g. if you try `document.querySelector("['closeButton']")` the browser will complain. While `document.querySelector("[closeButton]")` is executed correctly.